# Adding external library to my Angular 6 project only works when I'm running in localhost

Tags: angular, angular6, localhost, google-cast, dynamic-script-loading

I dynamically added the Chrome Api Library (from *https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js*) to my project, and works as expected when I run using **localhost:4200**. However it doesn't work when I run using my IP : **192.168.0.144:4200**. In this case the app runs, but the Chrome lib doesn't work.

This is my code:

```js
  cast: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ngOnInit()');

    const script = window['document'].createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1');
    window['document'].body.appendChild(script);

    window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = (isAvailable) => {
      if (isAvailable) {
        this.cast = window['chrome'].cast;
        const sessionRequest = new this.cast.SessionRequest('<MY_APP_ID>');
        const apiConfig = new this.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
          s => { },
          status => { if (status === this.cast.ReceiverAvailability.AVAILABLE) { } }
        );
        const x = this.cast.initialize(apiConfig, this.onInitSuccess, this.onInitError);
      } else {
        console.log('CAST API is not available !!');
      }
    };

  }
```

Works with **localhost**.

[image: chrome console(localhost)]

NOT working with the IP...

[image: chrome console(ip)]

I've already tried to add the lib in the *index.html*, instead of dynamically in the component, and got the same result.
I thought could be a CORS issue. Then I tried to config this proxy, without success:

```js
{
  "/v1": {
    "target": "https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

And changing this line:

```js
script.setAttribute('src', '/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1');
```

But only localhost keeps working...Help !

Comment: Still stucked here. I'm going to make a USD 50 Paypal transfer if someone solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this !! Chrome sender apps need to support **HTTPS**. So, I made a tunel with **ngrok** and worked.